# Realizing homotopy classes as thickened spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, surgery-theory

Suppose that we are given a smooth, closed, connected homology sphere $M^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with $n \geq 6$. I want to kill some elements in the fundamental group of $M$ by surgeries. As far as I understand it correctly, this is done by the following procedure:

1. Choosing a representative $S^1 \longrightarrow M$ of the element I want to kill (which can be chosen as an embedding)
2. Extending this to an embedding $\varphi : S^1 \times D^{n-1} \longrightarrow M$ and deleting the interior of the image in $M$
3. Gluing in a copy of $D^2 \times S^{n-2}$ along the boundary of $M \setminus \mathrm{int}(\varphi (S^1 \times D^{n-1}))$

I think I understand (via a Seifert-van-Kampen argument) why this procedure really kills the chosen homotopy class in the fundamental group.

My question is: How can I guarantee that I can represent my homotopy class in Step 1 by an embedding and why does the extension to an embedding of $S^1 \times D^{n-1}$ in Step 2 really exist?  Also, can this extension in Step 2) be done for embeddings of $k$-spheres in arbitrary dimension $k \leq n$?

Any help or literature where I can look things up are greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: As suggested in the comments, I looked at the tubular neighborhood theorem. However, I don't understand how this directly delivers the embeddings. In the literature, I found the condition that the normal bundle of the embedded $S^k$ has to be trivial. Can this be shown for the case at hand?

Comment: Do you already know how to prove that every homology sphere is orientable? Do you know the tubular neighborhood theorem?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I know that homology spheres are orientable, since they are closed and the top homology is $\mathbb{Z}$. However, I only ever encountered the tubular neighborhood theorem accompanied by a lot of hand-waving, so if you have a book where it is discussed i would be very grateful.

Comment: Hint: Prove that a smooth manifold is orientable if and only if the normal bundle of every smooth loop is trivial.